# Question about Markov Chains

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Is it true that for any real-valued Markov-chain $(X_n)_{n≥0}$ the sequence $(X_n+X_{n+1})_{n≥0}$
is again a Markov chain?
I have started with the definition, I need to check that :
$$P(Y_{n+1}=y_{n+1}|Y_0=y_0,...,Y_n=y_n)=P(Y_{n+1}=y_{n+1}|Y_n=y_n)$$
Where, $Y_n=X_n+X_{n+1}$

Now, using the definition of conditional probability:
$$P(Y_{n+1}=y_{n+1}|Y_0=y_0,...,Y_n=y_n)=\frac{P(Y_{n+1}=y_{n+1},Y_0=y_0,...,Y_n=y_n)}{P(Y_0=y_0,....,Y_n=y_n)}$$

Replacing with the values given of $Y_n=X_n+X_{n+1}$
$$\frac{P(X_{n+1}+X_{n+2}=y_{n+1},X_0+X_1=y_0,...,X_n+X_{n+1}=y_n)}{P(X_0+X_1=y_0,...,X_n+X_{n+1}=y_n)}$$

But, I am not clear how to conclude.

Comment: Start with the definition.

Comment: if X takes on only discrete set of values, answer is likely to be no

Comment: Yes, in this case is only the discrete set of values.